# Python Pyglet, new sprites in batch

Tags: python, sprite, pyglet

Python, pyglet

I want to add sprites to my window after it was drawn.

i try to use batch, becouse i want to to have lot of sprites.

my simple testing code is:

```
import pyglet
import random
from pyglet.window import key, mouse
from pyglet import image
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

#function return pyglet image 10x10px triangle, random color. Instead of loading a file, work fine
def pyimg():
    background = Image.new('RGBA', (10,10), (255,255,255,0) )
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (10,10), (0,0,0,0) )
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.polygon([(0,0), (0,10), (10,0)], fill=(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)))
    im= Image.alpha_composite(background, img)
    return pyglet.image.ImageData(im.width, im.height, 'RGBA', im.tobytes(), pitch=-im.width * 4)

screenWidth=1280
window = pyglet.window.Window(screenWidth, 720, resizable=True)

batch=pyglet.graphics.Batch()
sprites=[]
sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyimg(), x=50, y=50, batch=batch))
sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyimg(), x=150, y=50, batch=batch))

i=30

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()


@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global i
    if symbol == key.RETURN:
        print("Return key pressed")
        sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyimg(), x=150+i, y=50))
        i+=15

pyglet.app.run()
```

App displays two sprites, and should add one more after enter key pressed. How to update display?

Answer (score 1):

This line: `sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyimg(), x=150+i, y=50))` you aren't specifying the batch to add sprites into.

It needs to be `sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyimg(), x=150+i, y=50, batch=batch))`

Comment: Hah, few hours of seeking, a aswer is so simple. Works well.